# Why when I use nodejs child_processes fork function, mongoose save function not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, child-process

First I have nodejs project without child_proces,and mongo db.It works true,I get data and insert mongo db.

My schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TestSchema = new Schema({
  ID:String,
  username:String,
  full_name:String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Test',TestSchema);
```

Insert data

```
let testInsert = {
    ID:1,
    username:'test_user',
    full_name:'test_full'
};

let test = new Test(testInsert);

test.save(err => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else{
        console.log('insert')

    }
});
```

It works true,but when I use child_process test.save doesn't work,even doesn't enter in.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any other code, I can only presume the problem is the process is finishing before MongoDB has. Try changing your code to wait for `save` to complete e.g.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const test = new Test({
      ID:1,
      username:'test_user',
      full_name:'test_full'
    });
    await test.save();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
})()
```

Comment: I don't understand that why even doesn't enter in test.save(),

Comment: @VahagnAleksanyan `save` will be called but the application is probably exiting far too quickly for it to have time to reach or complete the MongoDB call, as I said with no other code to look at that's my incling. Have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes I try it but not working.When I comented child_process it works true.